# How to check is this function diffeomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds, diffeomorphism

I have a question related to diffeomorphism. I have to find on which set is this function $y= \frac{1}{e^x-1}$ a diffeomorphism. I found $y^{-1}=\ln \frac{1+y}{y}$ and the domain but how to check if this is $C^n$ class function?

Comment: So you are asking, for example, how many derivatives the function $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ has? Also, to improve your question you should be very explicit about what you already know regarding this function, i.e. exactly what its domain and range are. The formula $y^{-1}=\ln(\frac{1+y}{y})$ does not help in that regard, in fact that formula does not make much sense to me.

Comment: composition of diffeomorphisms is a diffeomorphism